# Why is the time evolution of occupied and unoccupied levels in a band under the influence of applied fields the same?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, time-evolution, electronic-band-theory, semiclassical

I am studying the semiclassical model for solid state physics as described in Chapter 12 of Ashcroft & Mermin. While I am familiar with the concept of holes, a formal argument is made in this chapter which to me seems circular. It all revolves around the following 'theorem':

*The unoccupied levels in a band evolve in time under the influence of applied fields precisely as they would if they were occupied by real electrons (of charge $-e$)*.

To be clear, I do not doubt this theorem nor do I have difficulties with it conceptually. My problem is with their formal proof of this statement (p. 226-227), which I quote here:

*This is because, given the values of $\mathbf{k}$ and  $\mathbf{r}$ at $t=0$, the semiclassical equations, being six first order equations in six variables, uniquely determine $\mathbf{k}$ and  $\mathbf{r}$ at all subsequent (and all prior) times, just as in ordinary classical mechanics the position and momentum of a particle at any instant determine its entire orbit in the presence of specified external fields. Because any point on an orbit uniquely specifies the entire orbit, two distinct orbits can have no points in common. We can therefore separate the orbits into occupied and unoccupied orbits, according to whether they contain occupied or unoccupied points at $t=0$. At any time after $t=0$ the unoccupied levels will lie on unoccupied orbits, and the occupied levels on occupied orbits. Thus the evolution of both occupied and unoccupied levels is completely determined by the structure of the orbits. But this structure depends only on the form of the semiclassical equations, and not on whether an electron happens actually to be following a particular orbit.*

Let me also quote the postulate given on p. 218 about the dynamics of the semiclassical model:

*The time evolution of the position and wave vector of an electron with band index $n$ are determined by the equations of motion:*
$$
\begin{align}
\dot{\mathbf{r}} &= \mathbf{v}_n (\mathbf{k}) = \frac{1}{\hbar} \frac{\partial \mathcal{E}_n (\mathbf{k})}{\partial \mathbf{k}} \\
\hbar \dot{\mathbf{k}} &= -e \left[ \mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r},t)+\frac{1}{c}  \mathbf{v}_n (\mathbf{k}) \times \mathbf{H}(\mathbf{r},t)    \right]
\end{align}
$$

This postulate only concerns the dynamics of the electrons, or to be more specific, of the levels occupied by electrons. In my opinion, in the proof given by Ashcroft & Mermin they are already assuming right from the start that these equations of motion also hold for unoccupied levels, thereby making their argument circular. The only thing they seem to rigorously prove is that two occupied orbits cannot be distinct if they have a common point in phase space ($rkt$-space). However, we do not know the dynamics of unoccupied levels (since this is what we seek to prove), so how can we then make a statement about occupied orbits not having a common point with unoccupied orbits? And how is it that we can then say that the structure of unoccupied orbits depends only on the form of the semiclassical equations?

Can anyone help me to make formal sense of their proof and show me that it is in fact not circular? Or give a different proof that the dynamics of unoccupied levels are the same?

**Edit 1**
With a different proof I mean one based on the postulates of semiclassical theory, not on the underlying quantum mechanics.

Comment: Its been a while since I dealt with this. Here is the point - a state in the band structure exists whether there is an electron there or not (occupied vs unoccupied). The time evolution of any state, occupied or unoccupied, can be determined by putting an electron there and watching it evolve. Since each state in a band structure is unique, it must evolve uniquely or you have a Pauli exclusion issue, which was explicitly considered when determining the band structure in the first place.

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for your reply. I understand how this follows in quantum mechanics, as there it is postulated how state vectors evolve in time, irregardless of occupation. Obviously, this should also hold for semiclassical theory if it is to provide us with a useful description of electron dynamics in solids. However, the issue I have with the approach of A&M is that they somehow pretend that the time evolution of unoccupied levels can be derived from a postulate concerning only the dynamics of occupied levels, without having to fall back on the more fundamental postulates of quantum theory.

Comment: Quantum mechanics is filled with situations where a semiclassical approach is taken to quantized states. One obvious example would be perturbation theory. Now, the time evolution of a level does not matter as to whether or not it is occupied - why should it?

Comment: Hi Jon, I think you missed my point, perhaps because I did not mention the word 'self-contained'. I do not know whether you own the A&M book, but there they explicitly state that it is their intention to construct semiclassical theory (SCT) as a self-consistent and self-contained theory, independent of quantum mechanics (QM) in a way that I will now explain. Obviously the postulates of SCT bear relations to those of QM, else it would be a rather useless framework, but all derived results within SCT should only be derived from the SCT postulates for the theory to be self-contained.

Comment: Now in QM it is postulated that the levels evolve in time according to the Schrodinger equation, independent on whether these levels are occupied or not. What they do in A&M is that they only make a postulate about the time evolution of occupied levels, and they then try to use that postulate to derive to time evolution of unoccupied levels. To me such an approach is nonsense, and if you look at their 'proof' it is rather circular. Both in QM and SCT you have to postulate (not derive) that the time evolution of occupied levels is the same as that of unoccupied levels.

Comment: I am well aware of A&M and have what is now a 40 year old copy. I think you need to re-read the beginning of Chapter 12 which contradicts your interpretation of what they are doing.

Comment: Hi Jon, here I strongly disagree with you. When considering the inertness of filled bands in said chapter, they explicitly use arguments based on the postulates of SCT instead of a simpler QM approach (see footnote 17). I quote "For logical consistency, however, it is necessary to demonstrate that this conclusion also follows directly from the semiclassical equations of motion, without reinvoking the underlying quantum mechanical theory that the model is meant to replace". Maybe this footnote is absent in older versions like yours?

Answer (score 0):

You may consider the following argument which freely accepts that the semiclassical equations of motion only apply to electrons. All this argument requires is that you also accept (as it seems you have) that the occupied orbits do not intersect the unoccupied orbits. Then, if you consider the phase space volume of unoccupied levels then this volume will evolve, en masse, according to the semiclassical equations. We can then validly choose/imagine that each unoccupied level is identified with the level it would have evolved from, had their been an electron there (we can make this choice since both are in the phase space volume of unoccupied levels at their respective times). In this argument, our statement that "unoccupied levels obey the semiclassical equations of motion" is a choice but since (per their 1. on page 225) we are only ever interested in integrating over all unoccupied levels to obtain a current due to a given band, the choice is free to be made.